# Eclipse code change working explanation

Tags: eclipse, build

If you are using Eclipse and your development server is running in the debugger, when you save your changes to this file, Eclipse compiles the new code automatically, then attempts to insert the new code into the already-running server. Changes to classes, JSPs, static files and appengine-web.xml are reflected immediately in the running server without needing to restart

plz any one can explain this ??????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For classes like JSP-files:
Its debugging using JPDA.

The IDE attach via socket to the JVM your running app and hot-redeploy the not-permanent-code (aka PermGen).

There are different techiques and frameworks for that:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Debugger_Architecture
```

Comment: BTW: Class structures, like the sigature of methods cant change.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't happen automatically. Check `Project --> Build Automatically` option. It should have been checked.

If you un-check it; then project will not be build/deployed automatically.